# Romberg integration of a vector in SciPy (Python)

Tags: python, scipy

Ok, what am I doing wrong? Scipy's romberg integrator is supposed to be able to handle vector functions, but I get an error...

```
import numpy
from numpy import array
from scipy import integrate

f = lambda x:array([1, x, x**2])
result = integrate.romberg(f, 0, 1, vec_func=True)
print(result)
```

Comment: `f` has to return a single value for each input value. If you set `vec_func=True`, what you are telling scipy is that, if it passes a vector of `n` values, your function will return a vector with the value of the function at those `n` points. Not that your return is multidimensional for a single input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document of `romberg` says:

> vec_func : bool, optional
>
> Whether func handles arrays as arguments (i.e whether it is a “vector” function). Default is False.

So, it's the argument x can be a vector.

Comment: Ah, ok. Not useful for what I want then. Thanks for the input.